# tar change permission of parent directory to 775

Tags: permissions, 22.04, tar

I tried to untar file with below command

```
sudo -u ubuntu tar -xzf tar.tgz -C "$(dirname "/home/ubuntu/deploy/")"
```

The tar log looks like

```
./
./deploy/deploy_scy.yml
./deploy/rollback_app.yml
./deploy/deploy_haproxy_single.yml
```

But the problem is that tar changed permission of /home/ubuntu from 750 to 775

```
root@ip-10-10-78-205:/home/ubuntu# ll
total 7016
drwxrwxr-x  7 ubuntu ubuntu    4096 Mar 21 07:41 ./
drwxrwxr-x 25 ubuntu ubuntu   12288 Mar 22 05:18 deploy/
```

How can I preserve the permission(750) of /home/ubuntu directory? This issue only happens in Ubuntu 22.04, I also don't understand why.

In Ubuntu 18.04, I use the same command, the permission /home/ubuntu still keeps as 750 as expected

Comment: It didn't change the parent directory. You can clearly see `./` in the output, which is `/home/ubuntu` in the command you ran. If you don't want the current working directory to be modified, you shouldn't be extracting it.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't change the parent directory. It change the *current* directory. You can clearly see `./` in the output, which is `/home/ubuntu` from the command you ran, and *that* directory got modified.

If you don't want the current working directory to be modified, you shouldn't be extracting `.`. Maybe instead extract just the `deploy` directory:

```
sudo -u ubuntu tar -xzf tar.tgz -C "$(dirname "/home/ubuntu/deploy/")" ./deploy
```

I can't reproduce this in an 18.04 Docker container (it behaved like you say 22.04 does), so I think your tar file was simply different in your 18.04 deployment.

---

There is a difference between these two ways of creating tar files in a directory containing a `deploy` directory:

```
tar cvf foo.tar ./deploy
tar cvf foo.tar .
```

The latter will contain an entry for `./` with the permissions of the current working directory in which it was ran. For example, the first command will result in:

```
% tar tvf foo.tar
drwxr-xr-x muru/muru 0 2023-03-22 14:46 ./deploy/
-rw-r--r-- muru/muru 0 2023-03-22 14:46 ./deploy/foo
```

vs. the following for the second command:

```
# tar tvf foo.tar
drwxr-xr-x muru/muru 0 2023-03-22 05:57 ./
drwxr-xr-x muru/muru 0 2023-03-22 05:46 ./deploy/
-rw-r--r-- muru/muru 0 2023-03-22 05:46 ./deploy/foo
```

When extracting, the latter will update the permissions of whichever directory it was in to the stored permissions. It's likely your tar file was created like the first one in 18.04 and like the second one in 22.04.

Comment: Actually, the tar file is the same.

Comment: Then either (a) something else prevented it from changing the permissions, or (b) it was a bug that was fixed but you don't have the latest updates in 18.04 yet. Either way, I'd consider the behaviour you say you see in 18.04 to be a bug and the one in 22.04 to be correct.